# Does a stack overflow always lead to a segmentation fault error?

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, runtime-error, stack-overflow

In Linux, when a running program attempts to use more stack space than the limit (a stack overflow), that usually results in a "segmentation fault" error and the execution is aborted.

Is it guaranteed that exceeding the stack space limit will always cause a segmentation fault error? Or could it happen that the program continues to run, possibly with some erroneous behavior due to data having been corrupted?

Another way of putting this: if a program misbehaves by producing wrong results but without a crash, can the cause still be a stack overflow?

Edit: to clarify, this question is not about "stack buffer overflow", it is about stack overflow, when the stack space used by the program exceeds the stack size limit (the limit that is in Linux given by `ulimit -s`).

Comment: At least theoretically [posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getrlimit.html) says there is no way round: `RLIMIT_STACK ....  If this limit is exceeded, SIGSEGV shall be generated ...`. But practice is practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A stack overflow turning into an access violation requires memory management hardware of some sort. Without hardware-assisted memory protection, an overgrown stack will collide with some other memory allocation, causing mutual corruption.

On demand-paged virtual memory operating systems, the upper limit of the stack is protected by a *guard page*: a page of virtual memory which is reserved (will not be allocated to anything) and marked "not present" so that accessing it generates a violation.  A guard page is only so many bytes wide; a stack pointer can still accidentally increment over the guard page and land in some unrelated writable memory (such as a mapping belonging to a heap allocation) where havoc will be wreaked without necessarily triggering any memory access violation.

In the C language we can easily cause large stack increments by declaring large, uninitialized non-`static` block-scoped arrays, like `char array[8192]; // (twice as large as a 4096 byte guard page)`. Using features like `alloca` or C99 variable-length arrays, we can do this dynamically: we can write a program which reads an integer value as a run-time input, and increments the stack by that much.

I debugged a problem many years ago whereby third-party code had debug logging macros, inside whose expansions there was a temporay array like `char print_buf[8192]` that was used for formatting messages. This was used in a multi-threaded application with many threads, whose stacks were reduced to just 64 kilobytes in size. Thanks to this `print_buf`, a thread's overflown stack leaped right past the guard page, and landed in another thread's stack, corrupting its local variables, causing the proverbial "hilarity to ensue".

Comment: Additionally, stack overflows can be leveraged to violate application security, another situation where they don't necessarily lead to a seg fault.

Comment: Great! If I am using some common Linux variant like Fedora or Ubuntu or something, is that then a demand-paged virtual memory operating system, so that the guard page protection you describe is used?

Comment: Yes, it's used. There's even a CVE about the guard page being "small" - https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2017-1000364/. The issue was also covered on LWN - https://lwn.net/Articles/725832/.